# How to clone project from the GitHub in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, git-clone

Hello all I am trying to clone the project from github. Is downloading the zip folder and loading it into the android studio the same as cloning from Github ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with android and programming

Comment: Git/GitHub is confusing as heck for beginners .. recommend the free Udacity course on it

Answer (score 8):

You can use this image :

File - > new -> Project from Version control -> GitHub

[image]

Comment: it requests github authentication. how does it work for cloning a public git project? why does it need to authenticate?

Comment: You can use this code: `git clone https://github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/AvdProgressbar.git`

Answer (score 5):

For cloning project from the terminal.

Step 1: Click this button:

[image: Clone or download button]

Step 2: Copy the link.

Step 3: Open the terminal, make sure you are in the folder where you want to clone the project. If you are not then just type: `cd theDesiredFolderLocation`. 
Next command: `git clone copiedLinkPath`.

Answer (score 1):

On github web, go to the repo you want yo clone and click on the download button (code) then copy the url where it says clone with https.

In Android Studio 4.0, go to VCS (if you've added a github plugin) then click on Get From Version Control, it will load a window where you'll paste in the url you got from github.

That's it, AS will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

First go to the GitHub and to the repository you want to clone.
[Click on the Code and copy the repository path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMQAy.jpg)

Next open your Android Studio. Make sure you have downloaded and installed git in your computer as well as set the git path[File->Settings->Git->Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaNef.jpg)

Next Clone the project
[File->New->Project From Version Control->Past the URL->Clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Ask.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

In android studio 3.6.3

File > New > Project from Version Control > Git

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Then go to GitHub.com 
Click on clone or download button.
copy the url and paste it on the android studio.